# End user browser and OS configuration

Tags: user-interface, browser

Sometimes in case of a bug in our code, we usually ask the end user to provide the browser configuration and OS configuration to isolate the issue. How can we get this information in case of a problem while the end users are accessing a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this information will be on the `user-agent` header. See some info [here](http://www.developershome.com/wap/detection/detection.asp?page=userAgentHeader).

However, this can be spoofed so should not be treated as gospel truth, nor do all browsers respect the fields and identify themselves properly.

Having said that, most people would not spoof it and the major browsers are reliable. So it can used as a general identifier for OS and browser.

You did not detail what configuration information you need, so this is of course only the basics.

Comment: Would it be possible to find OS information like operating system and  service pack or version level

Comment: @Joshua - most of the time this is information that is available on the user-agent

Comment: thanks, the following links were also useful http://nerds.palmdrive.net/useragent/code.html http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can get it with a PHP Function [get_browser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php). You can also get it with a JavaScript Code.